# Liqpay checkout API - return URLs on success, failure or cancellation

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I am working on integration of liqpay payment gateway to site using their available documentation at: https://www.liqpay.ua/en/doc/checkout.

so far I have integrated their checkout method (client-server). user clicks subscribe and it redirect user to liqpay checkout screen. but problem is when user cancel transaction or it is successful user. user just redirect back to given return flag available in their argument list. without any status code or message in url like other payment gateways do.
Need suggestions on it. if someone has experience in working with Liqpay.
[image]

Comment: Whats about the server_url?

Comment: It seems to be the case that they are passing the status via server2server call. You may catch and store it and may display it to the user on redirect page. Just a guess...

Comment: nop that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

While working around in admin panel i found some thing which help me upto some extent. with these settings i was able to get auto redirect to my site as well as some response from API after cancellation and successful payment. and when user cancel transaction it return back with "code" = cancel. attached are the settings and response in case it helps any one.

**Settings**
[image]

**Response**

[image]